# Reutilizar partes de código que se repiten varias veces

Tags: html

Para reutilizar código estoy creando ficheros independientes a los que simplemente llamo donde lo necesite con `require`. Funciona bien y no hay problema, pero tengo muchas partes de código, de 10 lineas, que me gustaría poder reutilizar también sin necesidad de crear un fichero independiente por cada trozo de código que quiero poder usar en distintos puntos.

¿Existe alguna forma de reunir todas esas partes de código que quieres reutilizar en UN sólo fichero? Con las funciones por ejemplo no uso más que un fichero y cuando quiero llamar a una en concreto lo hago por su nombre. Sé que puedo reutilizar código generando una función que me cree un array y después recorrerlo, pero me resulta bastante tedioso.

Comment: Justamente las funciones `require` o `include` están pensadas para este fin  , *reutilizar código* , si desea algo más avanzado para su finalidad puede emplear motores de plantillas _hay varias opciones_

Comment: Requiere o include. Es en PHP esta pregunta es solo html?

Comment: Si se trata de PHP puedes crear un fichero `llamaloComoQuieres.php` dentro del cual puedes requerir varios ficheros, y puedes definir algunas variables y constantes que sabes que las vas a necesitar muchas veces. Después en el código utilizas solo el `llamaloComoQuieres.php`

Answer (score 1):

Para la función que comentas lo mejor es utilizar motores de plantillas como PUG, mediante mixins puedes reutilizar el código que desees. Te dejo un ejemplo por si te interesa.

MIXIN que añade un elemento li con el argumento que le pasas:

```
mixin pet(name)
  li.pet= name
ul
  +pet('cat')
  +pet('dog')
  +pet('pig')
```

el output será

```
<ul>
  <li class="pet">cat</li>
  <li class="pet">dog</li>
  <li class="pet">pig</li>
</ul>
```

Si te interesa puedes ver más en [PUG](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html)

Comment: Efectivamente ademas que puedes tener mas de un mixin por archivo